Mint update fails due to uninstalled package
Trying to update Linux Mint 21.3 before I start upgrading to 22
sudo apt update fails with:

Err:2 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key
is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0686B78420038257

However, I had uninstalled the Brave Browser previously by right-clicking on its menu listing and choosing uninstall.
sudo apt update autoremove  after a reboot did not solve the problem.
How may I successfully update my system?

If that’s the only error, then you have successfully updated the local copies of the repository indexes you care about. apt update updates everything it can; errors related to a repository only affect that specific repository, nothing else.
To avoid the error, look for references to brave.com in /etc/apt/sources.list and files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d, and remove them.

No reference in /etc/apt/sources.list
Removed file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
Solved problem.
